# Django Rest Framework : Upload Image API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload image to my django website through django rest framework api.
but I am getting this error

> {
>       "detail": "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None" }

views.py

```
class UploadPhotoViewSet(APIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FormParser)

    def get(self, request,  format=None):
        model_object = Photo.objects.all()
        serializer = PhotoSerializer(model_object, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thumbnail = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
    source = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = '__all__'
```

model.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='photo', editable=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def upload_thumb_dir(self, filename):
        path = '/media/{}/photos/thumbs/{}'.format(self.project.id, filename)
        return path
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_thumb_dir, default='/default/photo.png', blank=True)

    def upload_photo_dir(self, filename):
        path = '/media/{}/photos/{}'.format(self.project.id, filename)
        return path
    source = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo_dir)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[image]

Comment: How exactly you upload your image? Via some JS framework?

Comment: I am using HTTPie – command line HTTP client, and its work fine for update text, read image but not uploading image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasted lot of time using curl and httpie.
The best and easy way is use [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

I found this way to command line upload image using Django Rest Framework.

```
import requests
files = {'thumb': open('D:/thumb.jpg', 'rb'), 'preview': open('D:/preview.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.put('/path/to/your/django/rest/api', data={'key': value, 'key2': 'value2'}, files=files)
print r.status_code
```

If you get 201, means you done.