# Multipart Parser In Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm trying to upload image using django rest framework. But I had a problem with that , when I'm using postman form it upload image successfully, but when I'm trying to type json as row in postman it returns to me this error.

> "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the
>   form."

here my code:

serializer.py

```
class UserImageCreateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = UserImages
        fields = ('user', 'image',)
```

view.py

```
class UserImageAPICreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UserImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserImageCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, AllowAnonymous]
```

my request:

> {
>     "User": 79,
>      "image": "/path/to/image.jpg"
>   }

note: when I use postman form it uploaded successfully and when use django rest framework HTML form it works too

I dont know what mistake I did.

so, any one has the solution please help me.

Comment: Actually, You can't upload any file as `JSON`. (`application/json). It should be either `form-data` or `mulipart-form` data

Comment: Aprt from that, why do you trying to upload image as raw JSON in POSTMAN?

Comment: thank you for your fast response.

because I used this API's from IOS app used swift so i need to deal with json not postman.

Comment: BTW, I tried to use  multipart-form but I think I have a lot to work with.
If can give me a simple example or reference to deal with that point?

Comment: I'm not familiar with IOS app, did you try something like this with POSTMAN? https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqklQ.png

Comment: when I used the same way of image you mentioned , it works fine without any problem but I dont know if multipart-form-data can be written as json or somthing else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182028/discussion-between-hishamdigital-and-jpg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you **can not upload** a image file by just giving a file path in your json upload data
like this:

```
{
"image": "/path/to/image.jpg"
}
```

If you send like this django will treat image data as normal string not a file

This is why you keep getting this error

```
"The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
```

you need to send image data,  not a image path.

here is python request example of upload image 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45611449/2679465